# Azure DocumentDB: order by and filter by DateTime

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM c 
WHERE c.DateTime >= "2017-03-20T10:07:17.9894476+01:00" AND c.DateTime <= "2017-03-22T10:07:17.9904464+01:00"
ORDER BY c.DateTime DESC
```

So as you can see I have a `WHERE` condition for a property with the type `DateTime`and I want to sort my result by the same one.
The query ends with the following error:

```
Order-by item requires a range index to be defined on the corresponding index path.
```

I have absolutely no idea what this error message is about :(

Has anybody any idea?

Comment: Have you added an index on the `DateTime` attribute in your collection? You would need to add that in order to use `Order By` clause in your query as the error indicates.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. I never used indexes in documentdb before, I will try it and let you know the result. Edit: not all my documents has the property `DateTime`, is indexing still possible?

Comment: `not all my documents has the property DateTime, is indexing still possible` - Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do one thing that don't require indexing explicitly. Azure documentBD is providing indexing on numbers field by default so you can store the date in long format. Because you are already converting date to string, you can also convert date to long an store, then you can implement range query.

Comment: The issue with the approach you're suggesting is that he would need to convert the data already stored in the collection from date to long.

Comment: Yahh in that case i would not recommend this approach, he needs to create index on date filed (requires extra space), but if he is just created new collection it would be the one of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a possible solution, thanks for pointing out the issue with the index.

As stated in the following article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-working-with-dates#indexing-datetimes-for-range-queries I changed the index for the datatype string to `RangeIndex`, to allow range queries:

```
DocumentCollection collection = new DocumentCollection { Id = "orders" };
collection.IndexingPolicy = new IndexingPolicy(new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 });
await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync("/dbs/orderdb", collection);
```

And it seems to work! If there are any undesired side effects I will let you know.

Comment: Even with that, the format you've chosen is troublesome because of the time-shift component at the end. "2017-03-20T10:07:17.9894476+01:00" is the same as "2017-03-20T09:07:17.9894476+00:00" but they have very different sort order. Now, if everything you do is in the same timezone, this won't be a problem, but to use ISO-8601 date string format in a cross-timezone situation, you need to use a no timeshift format, like "2017-03-20T09:07:17.9894476Z". Note, this complicates queries generated from user input because you'll need to shift the input to zulu time before composing the query.